# Too long of a question title makes the SE ads look really ugly

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, advertising

If a question title is too long, then it overflows onto the SE's logo, ending up in an extreme form of ugly:

[image: ugly ugly ugly!]

Comment: I saw this same thing.  Different font, but still too long.

Comment: This happens quite often! http://i.imgur.com/tsD6M.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're now selecting questions whose titles are between 40 and 75 characters long for these ads, instead of between 40 and 100. Such unattractive ads should be generated way less frequently now (hopefully never).